# How to achieve slick animation for hight of component with React Native on Android

Tags: react-native, react-animated

I am building a component that should animate its height based on interpolation of the Y position of a ScrollView. It works like charm in IOS but it work AWFUL with Android. By awful I mean, the animation is lagging painfully to the point it can't be used at all. I know you should add `useNativeDriver` to achieve great animation on android but there is two problem with it:

1. I cant add `useNativeDriver` on `interpolate` function.
2. I can't add `useNativeDriver` to animate height.

My code is:

```html
        <Animated.View
            style={{
                ...styles.imageContainer,
                height: !isCameraOpen ? 
                props.scrollY.interpolate({
                    inputRange: [ START_SCROLL_INPUT_HEIGHT, END_SCROLL_INPUT_HEIGHT ],
                    outputRange: [ START_SCROLL_OUTPUT_HEIGHT, END_SCROLL_OUTPUT_HEIGHT ],
                    extrapolate: 'clamp'
                }) : 
                START_SCROLL_OUTPUT_HEIGHT,
                transform: !isCameraOpen ? 
                [
                    {
                        scale: props.scrollY.interpolate({
                            inputRange: [ START_SCROLL_INPUT_SCALE, END_SCROLL_INPUT_SCALE ],
                            outputRange: [ START_SCROLL_OUTPUT_SCALE, END_SCROLL_OUTPUT_SCALE ],
                            extrapolate: 'clamp'
                        })
                    }
                ] : 
                []
            }}/>
```